# Updating a model association with an invalid id does not raise an exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, activerecord

Why when I try to update a model passing an invalid ID that references another model, an exception is not throw? It just do nothing and returns true.

Given the following migration:

```
create_table :conversations, id: :uuid do |t|
  t.references :contact, type: :uuid, null: false, foreign_key: true
  t.references :group, type: :uuid, foreign_key: true
  t.references :agent, type: :uuid, foreign_key: true
  t.timestamps
end
```

Controller

```
class Api::V1::ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
  before_action :set_conversation, only: [:update]

  def update
    @conversation.update!(conversation_params)
    render json: @conversation, status: :ok
  rescue ActionController::ParameterMissing => e
    render json: { error: e.message }, status: :unprocessable_entity
  rescue ActionController::UnpermittedParameters => e
    render json: { error: e.message }, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end

  private

  def conversation_params
    params.require(:conversation).permit(:group_id, :agent_id, :status)
  end

  def set_conversation
    @conversation = Conversation.find_by_id(params[:id])
    return unless @conversation.nil?

    render json: { error: 'The conversation you are trying to update was not found.' }, status: :not_found
  end
end
```

PUT request with payload :

```
{
    "group_id": "123456",
}
```

The group_id is not updated, but neither an exception is thrown.
I would like that an exception to be raised, so I could handle it and render a proper JSON response.

**EDIT**

Conversation model

```
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contact
  belongs_to :group, optional: true
  belongs_to :agent, optional: true
  validates_associated :contact
  validates_associated :group
  validates_associated :agent
end
```

Comment: What validations do you have on the ``Conversation`` model?

Comment: I edited the post with the Conversation model.